# Issue with Upgrading TinyMCE version to 5 on FormBuilder

Tags: javascript, formbuilder, tinymce-5

We have been using [FormBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/) to build forms wherein we use TextArea with [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) (version 4.* by default).

We tried to upgrade the TinyMCE library by replacing the existing TinyMCE CDN link - with version 5.* CDN link - in to form-builder.min.js.

`this.js=["https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"]`

to

`this.js=["https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"]`

After upgrade, it started giving issues when we have multiple TinyMCE elements on a single page as shown in the image:

[TinyMCE with Form Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHAGb.png)

Have also tried to include self hosted TinyMCE library which is also giving the same issue. The TinyMCE version 4 was working fine when we use from CDN, but including local libraries for TinyMCE 4.* and using CDN for TinyMCE 5.* is also not working.

Looking for help to correctly upgrade the TinyMCE version on FormBuilder.

Thanks.

Comment: According to TinyMCE, our access to version 4 will be expired on February 25 2021 but when we contacted TinyMCE they suggested we'll reach out to FormBuilder